# OBSOLETE - pyso.py - Python Stack Overflow library

Tags: library, python, obsolete

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

```
import pyso

# Install the Server Fault API version 1.0.
pyso.install_site(pyso.APISite("api.serverfault.com", "1.0"))

# Get all the names of the moderators.
print list((m["display_name"] for m in pyso.get_all_moderators()))

# Get question titles by user ID.
print list(q["title"] for q in pyso.get_users_questions(59180))
```

### About

This is a simple Python module providing functions for querying Stack Overflow. I created it mostly because I was interested and because I wanted something small (it's not even 400 lines). It's simple; it works with Stack Overflow out of the box. Just `import pyso` and start calling the functions. All results are Python dicts and/or lists, a straight deserialization provided by a json module. A generator is returned by functions that return multiple items.

All the functions are backed by a simple APISite class that does all the data fetching. To access another Stack Exchange site call `install_site()` with a new `APISite` instance created with the site API URL, e.g. "api.serverfault.com". Also, in cases where there isn't a pyso level function available this class can be used to make your a request. As well, there isn't a whole of error handling or documentation, so read the source.

#### License

GPL version 2 for now.

#### Download

Source code is available at github.com

Home page: http://github.com/jwatney/pyso
Repository: git://github.com/jwatney/pyso.git

#### Platform

Works with Python 2.6. Not sure about other versions.

### Contact

Contact me at jonathonwatney at gmail dot com, or through the issue tracker at github if you have a bug or feature request.

Comment: Thanks guys. Feel free to leave a comment here if you end up using it or know someone who does.

Comment: Link to the repo is dead now

Answer (score 2):

I like this library because I can look at it and easily understand what bit does what. It's not very "ergonomic" right now, however. I'd like to be able to write code like this...

```
#determine what bumped this question at the top of the homepage
top_questions_on_homepage = pyso.get_all_questions(order_by="activity")
question = top_questions_on_homepage.next()
pyso.get_questions_timeline(question["question_id"],
                            start_date = question["last_activity_date"])
```

...but `get_questions_timeline` doesn't want a numeric ID, or a list of numeric IDs, but a semicolon separated string of IDs. The problem is kinda worse with `start_date`, because the library expects... er, something it can call `int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))` on to get back exactly the `start_date` value I got from the API.

Food for thought.