# Python library for the StackExchange v2 API?

Tags: discussion, api-v2, python, app-request

So I'm aware of [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/q/198/10599) and [pyso.py](https://stackapps.com/q/1722/10599), but neither covers the v2.0 API. Does anyone know of a Python library for the 2.0 API?

Answer (score 5):

I think **Py-StackExchange** is your best bet. There's a [wiki page on updating to v2 API](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/wiki/Updating-to-v2.x).

Answer (score 3):

## Stack.PY

[George Edison](https://stackapps.com/users/18/12019) has announced [Stack.PY](https://stackapps.com/q/3417/12019), with support for 2.1.