# Python library 2.2 API Wrapper?

Tags: discussion, python, app-request, api-v2.2

Is there a Python library that encompasses the new functionality in the 2.2 API?

I've seen this [question](https://stackapps.com/questions/3340/python-library-for-the-stackexchange-v2-api) and this [question](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-api-client-libraries-grouped-by-programming-language), and the comments indicating that libraries were being created and updated to use the 2.0 API, but the code in [Stack.PY](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackpy/trunk/files) hasn't been touched in almost two years and the [2.0 branch](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tree/updating-2.0) of Py-StackExchange still seems to be very early in development. The others mentioned in the second question appear to be at 2.1.